# Setting Active Admin namespace using active admin config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, activeadmin

I am using active admin with devise and im trying to set namespace for all my active admin routes.

In active_admin.rb i have set the default_namespace as,

```
config.default_namespace = :abc_123
```

In the route i have,

```
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
```

The routes generated are such,

```
                           root GET        /                                              pages#home
         new_admin_user_session GET        /abc_123/login(.:format)                  active_admin/devise/sessions#new
             admin_user_session POST       /abc_123/login(.:format)                  active_admin/devise/sessions#create
                     admin_root GET        /admin(.:format)                              admin/dashboard#index
              abc_123_root GET            /abc_123(.:format)                        abc_123/dashboard#index
            abc_123_quotes GET            /abc_123/quotes(.:format)                 abc_123/quotes#index
                           POST           /abc_123/quotes(.:format)                 abc_123/quotes#create
         abc_123_quote     GET        /abc_123/quotes/new(.:format)             abc_123/quotes#new
        edit_abc_123_quote GET        /abc_123/quotes/:id/edit(.:format)        abc_123/quotes#edit
             abc_123_quote GET        /abc_123/quotes/:id(.:format)             abc_123/quotes#show
batch_action_abc_123_users POST       /abc_123/users/batch_action(.:format)     abc_123/users#batch_action
             abc_123_users GET        /abc_123/users(.:format)                  abc_123/users#index
```

The login works i am able to login with my activeadmin account but on dashboard it breaks with the error,

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `abc123_users_path' for ActiveAdmin::Helpers::Routes:Module):
1: insert_tag active_admin_application.view_factory["page"]
```

It breaks for all the other active admin page too with the same error.
I don't have the 'abc123_users_path' path in my route. Im not getting from where this route is getting added to the active admin page.

Comment: what if you define the namespace without underscores (eg `abc123`)?

Comment: yeah without underscore it works but not with underscore. Is it an activeadmin issue? 
Even if i configure using string, config.default_namespace = 'abc_123'
it still throws same error.

Comment: I don't know what's happening, but I always define namespaces without underscore.

Comment: I'm going out on a limb, and guessing that the awnser is in this code https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb

Comment: Did you get any further with this? I am getting an identical error after updating to the latest version of ActiveAdmin. Looking at the stack trace, it seems to be some sort of issue with generating the route for one of the resources. I'd be interested to know if you found a fix?

Comment: No Max, i'm still facing this issue for now i'm using namespace without underscore. I have also posted the issue on activeadmin github page, haven't got reply yet.
https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3962