# ActiveAdmine register_page and controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

What will be the link to an action defined like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "such_page" do


  content title: 'A page' do
    columns do
      column do
        render partial: 'index'
      end
    end
  end # content

  action_item do
    link_to('Perform', 'such_page/much_action')
  end

controller do
    def much_action
      puts 'Wow, actually doing!'
      redirect_to 'http://stackoverflow.com'
    end
end
```

I supposed that link will be just like mentioned in `action_item`, but is leads to 404 error page. Did I forgot to add some routes or am I wrong about how ActiveAdmin `register_page` and controller cooperate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Active Admin pages you'll have to define a custom action like so:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "such_page" do

  #... 

  action_item do
    # please refer to rake routes for the exact route name
    link_to('Perform', admin_much_action_path)
  end

  page_action :much_action do
    puts 'Wow, actually doing!'
    redirect_to 'http://stackoverflow.com'
  end

  #...

end
```

by using `page_action` a route will be configured automatically. You can make sure the action is available by calling `rake routes`.

Reference: http://activeadmin.info/docs/10-custom-pages.html

Comment: Tried that, got `undefined method `collection_action' for #<ActiveAdmin::PageDSL:0x007f3649910fd8> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Sorry just realized this is a page not a resource. I've updated the answer to use `page_action` instead of `collection_action`.

Comment: Got Routing Error, but there is `admin_such_page_much_action_path` record in routes. Tried to use it and got Routing Error again. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: can you try to put `action_item` below `page_action` block? Seems like `page_action` is not recognized before it's defined.

Answer (score 1):

It seems ActiveAdmin have some problems with underscores as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30254926/setting-active-admin-namespace-using-active-admin-config).

Try rename your page like this

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Such Page" do
  ...
end
```

and you will get this in your routes

```
admin_such_page GET         /admin/such_page(.:format)       admin/such_page#index
```